# What param is expected in getBaseUrl() function in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, url, media

I want to return the image URL using `getBaseUrl()` function but I can't understand what value to set to the **`$value`** variable.

```
$url = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(
    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/category/' . $value;
```

Comment: are you looking to used this function for fetching image from media?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya, to fetch images from categories of the catalog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$value` needs to be the name of the image filename.
e.g. my_category_image.jpg

For example:

Place an image in pub/media/catalog/category/my_category_image.jpg then use `$value = my_category_image.jpg` to test and see if it appears:

```
http://magento-site.com/pub/media/catalog/category/my_category_image.jpg
```

Comment: I marked your answer as right because when you know the image name, the function returns the full URL of the image, but I wanted to return dynamic images from the category of catalog and I did that with other method. Thank's.